# google maps API driving distance is inaccurate

Tags: php, google-maps, cakephp

I cant get Google API to give the same answer for driving distance as when using Google maps. I use this data to test the accuracy of the API vs Google Maps. I am using cakephp but php code is also acceptable.

```
Test data for lat/long (not people I know) 
(point1)
Address Lat: -38.041968
Address Long: 145.26416599999993 

(point 2)
 Address Lat: -37.988981
Address Long: 145.53447499999993
```

The distance between these 2 points on Google maps says 41.3km but on the Google api below for the same lat/long points I get 33.7km which is too inaccurate to rely on. What is going on with Google API as it doesnt seem to work?

```
  $stlat = $student['Student']['address_lat'];
  $stlong = $student['Student']['address_long'];
  foreach ($tutors  as $key => $item):
     $tutlat = $item['Tutor']['address_lat']; //this is the lat/long above
     $tutlong = $item['Tutor']['address_long'];
     $testUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$stlat.",".$stlong."&destinations=".$tutlat.",".$tutlong."&mode=driving&language=en&sensor=false";
     $data1 = file_get_contents($testUrl);
     $data = utf8_decode($data1);
     $obj = json_decode($data1);
     $dist2=$obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
     debug($obj->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text); //km
 endforeach;
```

Comment: are the Travel Modes the same?

Comment: Yes, and the purpose of showing you the data is that you can test for yourself. That way someone can see if I did something wrong or the Google API doesnt work

Comment: odd i get 33.8km using google maps - want to double check that https://www.google.com/maps/dir/-38.041968+145.26416599999993+/-37.988981+145.53447499999993+/@-38.0275333,145.3252371,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!4m8!1m3!2m2!1d145.264166!2d- so my map usage matches your API, i think your original map check is faulty.38.041968!1m3!2m2!1d145.534475!2d-37.988981

Comment: i dont get that value in google maps as i still get 40Km +, how do I fix the goolge map and also I tried on another computer for the same result. I am using KM and not miles

Comment: im using km to - still get 33.8km - odd

Comment: what i get: http://imgur.com/UYqozfi

Comment: I can see, google maps is not giving the shortest route, as the API is.

Comment: is for me, must hate you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that on google maps I am not getting the optimum distance, but on the API I am. So the problem is solved